# Which proccess is fastest a SQL Server query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got a question from my interviewer but I couldn't answer that. There is one row if you query for database to CREATE SELECT DELETE UPDATE which one is fastest and which one is slowest? and why? (in same condition data) He said if you know the how database system works, you ought to know.

Comment: "which one is fastest or slowest?" Do you mean "which one is fastest and which one is slowest?"

Comment: yes .. Thx I editing my question

Answer (score -1):

None of these are faster or slower in general terms.  Speed depends on a great many things, not the least of which include indexing, the size of the dataset (at least for the DML options you listed -- 'create' is DDL, so not really in the same category as the others), hardware performance, and so on.

Comment: Thanks you a lot It's very helped  to me. I know it depends on many things , But the Interviwer asked me So I confused . Thanks a lot